# Save a BufferedImage object to Amazon S3 as a file

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I currently make use of the following to upload a file to S3:

```
File file = new File(my_file_path);

AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(cred));

s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("folder", key, file));
```

The above works fine but I want to directly save a `BufferedImage` to S3 to shave a few seconds from my application but I have no clue on how to do this? This is how I currently save my image to a file:

```
image = new BufferedImage(rawImage.width, rawImage.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

File file = new File(filepath); 

ImageIO.write(image, "png", file);
```

Is there a way to do the writing directly to Amazon S3 as a stream, if so, can someone show an example?

In addition, is this a good idea? If its prone to errors, I'll stick to my current method. Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The following (or something very similar) should work fine. Avoiding the step of writing to a physical file should be slightly less error-prone than dealing with disk I/O (at the very least, your chances of filling up your disk over time are reduced).

```
BufferedImage image = ...
ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(image, "png", os);
byte[] buffer = os.toByteArray();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(new PropertiesCredentials(cred));
ObjectMetadata meta = new ObjectMetadata();
meta.setContentLength(buffer.length);
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest("folder", key, is, meta));
```

Comment: This worked great, thank you jkraybill! I would add the content type `meta.setContentType("image/png");` since when I tried to open it in the AWS S3 console it kept downloading it rather than letting me view the image. Just so that future readers of this question don't trip up on this. :)

Comment: Would you guys know why an image I read from a URL as an inputStream and then I upload to S3 when I try to access via browser instead of see the image on browser it gets downloaded?

Comment: @franzmobile - you have the wrong content type set for the image, or have not set a content type. see the "Abs" comment above for the type of thing that should fix it.

Comment: @FranciscoSouza The problem you are facing is mainly because of the 'Content-Disposition' Response Header, If you set is as 'Inline' while creating a signed URL, you get the OCTET Stream instead using which you can directly preview

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using the TransferManager API in the AWS SDK.  You can read more about it at the [AWS blog post](http://java.awsblog.com/post/Tx2Q9SGR6OKSVYX/Amazon-S3-TransferManager).  The following is a snippet regarding its advantage:

> Behind this simple API, TransferManager is doing a lot of work for you. Depending on the size and data source for your upload, TransferManager adjusts the algorithm it uses to process your transfer, in order to get the best performance and reliability. Whenever possible, uploads are broken up into multiple pieces, so that several pieces can be sent in parallel to provide better throughput. In addition to higher throughput, this approach also enables more robust transfers, since an I/O error in any individual piece means the SDK only needs to retransmit the one affected piece, and not the entire transfer.