# Uploading BufferdImage object using Amazon SDK for java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a BufferedImage object to S3 Amazon bucket. But the SDK accepts File object as the third parameter in the following overloaded method:

```
s3client.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, keyName, file));
```

I have a BufferedImage object and i want an implicit way to convert it into a File object and upload it.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of file is a `BufferedImage` in your opinion?

Comment: It doesn't matter what is the kind.

Comment: Sure it matters. You don't have to create an actual file if you use the `PutObjectRequest(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)` constructor, but you still need to decide what the byte representation is. Is it `JPEG`, `PNG`, `RAW` or some custom format. Since `BufferedImage` is not `Serializable`, there's no default mapping for `BufferedImage` -> `byte[]` or vice versa.

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for the helpful comment. Actually i have just tried your  suggested constructor and it works, but i set the metadata object value to null. The resultant uploaded image cannot be opened. Any suggestions?

Comment: Yea, I suggest you make it non-null.

Comment: @Kayaman Actually i have did it null and got warning in the log that i must at least pass the content length of the inputstream. The file/image uploads to S3 bucket fine but when i try to open it it doesn't recognize it as an image and its size by the way is 0 bytes. Could you please tell me by code what to pass in the metaobject parameter to make sure the uploaded image will open successfully? Thanks

Comment: I recommend you read the documentation and learn it yourself. It's how I do things instead of relying on other people to tell me what to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save a BufferedImage object to Amazon S3 as a file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6727207/save-a-bufferedimage-object-to-amazon-s3-as-a-file)